Virtual machine - Partition resize won't work
I have a virtual machine with Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS on ESXI. I want to increase my disk. Here is what I did step by step.

Go to ESXI and shutdown the VM.
Increase the Disk Size +30GB in Edit Settings. (200GB -> 230GB) Then Power on the machine.
Launch a web console and switch to the root user.

After that, I followed these steps:
# lsblk

The output :

NAME                      MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
loop0                       7:0    0    64M  1 loop /snap/core20/2379
loop1                       7:1    0  63.7M  1 loop /snap/core20/2434
loop2                       7:2    0 206.2M  1 loop /snap/flutter/141
loop3                       7:3    0 206.3M  1 loop /snap/flutter/145
loop4                       7:4    0  91.9M  1 loop /snap/lxd/24061
loop5                       7:5    0  91.9M  1 loop /snap/lxd/29619
loop6                       7:6    0  44.1M  1 loop /snap/snapd/22991
loop7                       7:7    0  38.8M  1 loop /snap/snapd/21759
sda                         8:0    0   230G  0 disk
├─sda1                      8:1    0     1M  0 part
├─sda2                      8:2    0   1.5G  0 part /boot
└─sda3                      8:3    0 198.5G  0 part
  └─ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv 253:0    0 198.5G  0 lvm  /
sr0                        11:0    1  1024M  0 rom

As we can see, sda increased to 230GB. I wanted to increase the volume of :
  └─ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv 253:0    0 198.5G  0 lvm  /

Because I am running out of space on / path.
# df -h
Filesystem                         Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev                                16G     0   16G   0% /dev
tmpfs                              3.2G  9.2M  3.2G   1% /run
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv  196G  169G   19G  91% /
tmpfs                               16G     0   16G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                              5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs                               16G     0   16G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/loop0                          64M   64M     0 100% /snap/core20/2379
/dev/loop2                         207M  207M     0 100% /snap/flutter/141
/dev/loop3                         207M  207M     0 100% /snap/flutter/145
/dev/loop1                          64M   64M     0 100% /snap/core20/2434
/dev/loop4                          92M   92M     0 100% /snap/lxd/24061
/dev/loop5                          92M   92M     0 100% /snap/lxd/29619
/dev/loop6                          45M   45M     0 100% /snap/snapd/22991
/dev/loop7                          39M   39M     0 100% /snap/snapd/21759
/dev/sda2                          1.5G  210M  1.2G  16% /boot
tmpfs                              3.2G     0  3.2G   0% /run/user/1000
tmpfs                              3.2G     0  3.2G   0% /run/user/997

I used cfdisk

I selected the Resize button and pressed enter.

Then I quit, and I followed these commands in order:
# partprobe
# pvresize /dev/sda3
  Physical volume "/dev/sda3" changed
  1 physical volume(s) resized or updated / 0 physical volume(s) not resized
# lvextend -l +100%FREE /dev/ubuntu-vg/ubuntu-lv
  New size (50815 extents) matches existing size (50815 extents).
# resize2fs /dev/ubuntu-vg/ubuntu-lv
resize2fs 1.45.5 (07-Jan-2020)
The filesystem is already 52034560 (4k) blocks long.  Nothing to do!

I think I am missing some steps or doing something wrong.
Thanks in advance to anyone who tries to help.
I tried the same steps exactly on another virtual machine and I was able to extend the partition on that one.
